# "TransitionRejection" trying to download a file with a new element from JS using selenium

Tags: javascript, perl, selenium, download

I want to automate the download from a lot of files of a website.
In order to do it I iterate through many pages getting the id from the files. I do this using selenium and a perl script.

As there is no functionality to directly download a file in selenium, and I can not use some kind of curl because I need the session from selenium I'm trying to use the following workaround which I had already used in other projects.

I create a JS element and execute a script with the url for each file, for example:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute("href", "https://myurl.com/id1/export?format=TCX");
a.setAttribute("download", "https://myurl.com/id1/export?format=TCX");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

But when I try to do this I become the following error in the script:

> Error while executing command: stale element reference: The element
>   reference of 
>   is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is
>   not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
>   at /Library/Perl/5.18/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 391.  at
>   /Library/Perl/5.18/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 348.

If I reproduce it directly in the firefox console I get this:

> TransitionRejection(type: 2, message: The transition has been
>   superseded by a different transition, detail: Transition#2(
>   'top.ids.info.byId'{"myId1":"XXXXX","myId2":"YYYYYY"} ->
>   'home'{"feedId":null,"tag":null} ))

If I just access the url with a normal GET from the browser I get the download prompt without problems. (As long as I'm logged in)

If I get the url with selenium it works for the first url, but then it stays stuck there and does not download the second file.

```
  $driver->get($download_url1); # This one is downloaded
  $driver->get($download_url2); # This line is not executed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve the problem with javascript, instead of generating the element as I did I added some attributes in order to replicate the website normal function, and changed the url from:

```
https://myurl.com/id1/export?format=TCX
```

to

```
/id1/export?format=TCX
```

so the code looks like this:

```
my $script = 'var a = document.createElement("a");' .
    'a.setAttribute("ng-href", "' . $url_to_download .'");' .
    'a.setAttribute("target", "_self");' .
    'a.setAttribute("class", "button button-default button-block");' .
    'a.setAttribute("ng-click", "dismiss()");' .
    'a.setAttribute("href", "' . $url_to_download .'");' .
    'document.body.appendChild(a);' .
    'a.click();' .
    'document.body.removeChild(a);';
```